# One to many relationship in NEAR protocol using rust

Tags: rust, nearprotocol

I am trying to use one to many relationships using near_sdk [Map](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Map.html) and [Vector](https://docs.rs/near-sdk/0.10.0/near_sdk/collections/struct.Vector.html).

```
use near_sdk::collections::Map;
use near_sdk::collections::Vector;

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct ProfileDetails {
    profileTags: Map<String, IdProducts>,
}

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct Products { 
    product_name: String,
    product_details: String,
} 

#[near_bindgen]
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
pub struct IdProducts {
      products: Vector<Products>,
}
```

With rust native collections it's done using push method e.g.

```
 let mut hash_map: HashMap<u32, Vec<Sender>> = HashMap::new()
 hash_map.entry(3)
      .or_insert_with(Vec::new)
      .push(sender)
```

How to push using near protocol collections?

```
#[near_bindgen]
impl ProfileDetails {
    pub fn set_profile(&mut self, product_name:String, product_details:String) {
        let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
        p = Products {
            product_name,
            product_details
        };
        self.profileTags.insert(&account_id, ???);

    }
}
```

Solidity example is here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/39705/56408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can only have #[near_bindgen] on one struct which represents the contract itself. To implement `set_profile`, you can create a persistent vector with a proper prefix (`account_id` for example). So it would look like

```rust
let account_id = env::signer_account_id();
p = Products {
    product_name,
    product_details
};
let mut id_products = Vector::new(account_id.into_bytes());
id_products.push(&p);
self.profileTags.insert(&account_id, &id_products);
```

If your collection is small, you can also use `Vec` from standard library.

Comment: new gives error: let mut products_list = Vector::new(id);
   |             -----------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T`

Comment: You can annotate the variable: `let mut id_products: Vector<IdProducts> = ...`